# Stormcrawler workaround for pages with http 405 code

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I wanted to crawl a webpage like [this](https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/lenovo+320+15abr+80xs009bge/incrpc/topprod) one.

It seems that I get a 405 error

```
2018-04-09 11:18:40.930 c.d.s.b.FetcherBolt FetcherThread #2 [INFO] [Fetcher #3] Fetched https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/lenovo+320+15abr+80xs009bge/incrpc/topprod with status 405 in msec 53
```

The page seems to have crawler protection. Is it possible to still crawl it using stormcrawler together with selenium maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site does not disallow robots but returns a 405 if the user agent does not look like a browser. You can reproduce the issue with curl

```
curl -A -I "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/lenovo+320+15abr+80xs009bge"

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html
Server: nginx
Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
X-Distil-CS: BYPASS
Expires: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 10:48:02 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 10:48:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" -I "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/lenovo+320+15abr+80xs009bge"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Server: nginx
Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
Expires: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 10:48:26 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 10:48:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

One workaround could be to use selenium as suggested or simply to change the user agent so that it mimics what a browser would use. Not great, as it is always preferable to be open about your crawler but in that particular case, the site would prevent crawlers in their [robots.txt](https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/robots.txt) if that was their intention.

You can change the user agent via configuration in StormCrawler.